# Django slug link edit page not found

Tags: python, django, slug

I'm having trouble, when I use slug for my url. it said no post matches the query.

The troubles occuring in edit and delete page, it turns out still working fine within the detail page.

But the weird thing is the 404 error was raised by post.views.post_detail, not post_update.

my urls inside the post app

```
urlpatterns = [

url(r'r^$', post_list, name='list'),
url(r'^create/$', post_create, name='create'),
url(r'^(?P<slg>[\w-]+)/$', post_detail, name='detail'),
url(r'^(?P<slg>[\w-]+)/edit/$', post_update, name='update'),
url(r'^(?P<slg>[\w-]+)/delete/$', post_delete),

]
```

the views

```
def post_detail(request, slg=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slg=slg)
    context = {
    "title":intance.title,
    "instance":instance
    }
    return render(request, "post_detail.html", context)

def post_update(request, slg=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slg=slg)
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    context = {
        "title":instance.title,
        "instance":instance,
        "form", form,
    }
    return render(request, "post_form.html", context)
```

the get_absolute_url function also already return slg.
the only problem is the post not found in edit page, even the slg title has a match with the current available posts.

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
December 23, 2016 - 17:52:00
Django version 1.9.7, using settings 'blog.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Not Found: /hahaha/edit/
[23/Dec/2016 17:52:08] "GET /hahaha/edit/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1725
```

it's like the post_update function won't execute.

what could possibly be wrong ?
thank you.

Comment: So _this_ is what your going to start doing in your spare time now that your presidential term is ending?

Comment: Looks like you have a couple of missing `'`.

Comment: Please post the  real code and the full traceback

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Actual, [its not to far from the truth](https://www.wired.com/2014/12/obama-becomes-first-president-write-computer-program/)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing single quote `'` in your urls. url patterns should be valid `str`

```
url(r'r^$', post_list, name='list'),
url(r'^create/$', post_create, name='create'),
#              ^
url(r'^(?P<slg>[\w-]+)/$', post_detail, name='detail'),
#                       ^
url(r'^(?P<slg>[\w-]+)/edit/$', post_edit, name='edit'), 
#                            ^
url(r'^(?P<slg>[\w-]+)/delete/$', post_delete),
#                              ^
```

Comment: Pardon me, for my typo writing the code in the question, thank you for your help, but I'm pretty sure that it's not what troubling me. I don't know or do you know somewhere that I should might check ?